# Backbone.js initializing views for collection data where dom elements already rendered on the server

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone-views, backbone.js-collections

I'm working on a backbone.js SPA for displaying a users contacts for users of our site.

My Backbone application consists of three views:
AppView - view for the collection of contact list items
createContactView - view for the form for adding new contacts
ContactView - view for each contact item

A Collection: ContactList
And a model: Contact

The markup consists of an ordered list  with an id="address-list", containing list items

of contact information whose id's correspond to the contact_id of the list item.

I have provided a bootstrapped Javascript array of JSON objects that represent each contact that is represented in the list item.

In my first swag at this project I conformed to an example for a todo list in the book Developing Backbone.js Applications by Addy Osmani. The example used bootstrapped data to create the TodoViews when the app instantiates, and then renders the view and appends it to the TodoList view of the example.
The main app then listensTo the collection of Todos and when the add event fires will create another Todo view and appends it to the Todo list.

So I initially followed this example for my address book SPA and everything worked great, each ContactView rendered in the dom and was appended to the address-list, and all events were attached to their respective buttons for updating and deleting the contact.

Backbone recommends for efficiency sake to create the markup for the initial view of the contacts list on the server side.

So I refactored my server side code to render the initial contact list items within the address-list ordered list.

So on the client side I still create the collection from bootstrapped contact information, create a view but not calling the render method since it already exists in the dom. I have provided an el in the bootstrapped data thinking that is how the view would attach itself to the correct dom element so all my events will connect to their respective elements for updating and deleting a contact, but this never happens.

So my question is how do I create a view from existing dom elements with bootstrapped data when I dont have to render it because it already exists in the Dom ?

Following is the code that I am using, followed by an example of the bootstrapped data. Thanks for any help you can provide.

**Javascript:**

```js
// The main application view controller.
var AppView = Backbone.View.extend({

    // el binds the AppView to the existing ordered
    // list of contacts presented on the client.
    el: $("#address-list"),
    addressbookRouter: '',
    createContactView: '',
    contacts: '',
    contactViews: [],
    sort: 'lastName',

    // Initialize the AppView application.
    initialize: function(contactsData) {
        console.debug('AppView.initialize');

        // initialize the ContactsCollection
        // - contactsData is a bootstrapped json object
        //   of contacts created on the server side.
        this.contacts = new ContactsCollection(contactsData); 
        this.listenTo(this.contacts, 'add', this.render, this);

        // initialize a ContactView for each contact in the collection.
        this.createContactViewsForCollection(this.contacts);

        // initialize the AppRouter for
        // sorting of contacts on the client.
        this.addressbookRouter = new AppRouter();
        this.listenTo(this.addressbookRouter, 'route', this.render, this);

        // initialize the CreateContactView
        // - used for adding new contacts to the
        //   contacts collection and updating wombat.
        this.createContactView = new CreateContactView(this.contacts);

    },

    // Add a ContactView and render.
    // - contact is a JSON object
    addContactView: function(contact) {
        console.debug('AppView.addContactView');

        // - create contact view
        // - render the view
        var view = new ContactView(
            {model: contact
        });
        this.$el.append( view.render().el );
    },

    // Instantiate a view for each contact in the collection.
    createContactViewsForCollection: function(contacts) {
        console.debug('AppView.createViewsForCollection');

        this.contacts.each(
            function( contact ) { 
                this.contactViews.push(
                    new ContactView({
                        model: contact
                    })
                );
            }, this 
        );
    },

    // Render contact views for the ContactsCollection
    // - render will be called in the following cases
    //   1. A column header has been clicked, and a
    //      sort order based on that header is passed in
    //      and set to this.sort.
    //   2. A new contact has been added to the collection
    //      resulting in a Backbone Model being passed to the
    //      function, with this.sort as the sort order.
    render: function(sort) {
        console.debug('AppView.render');
        
        // determine the sort order
        // for the collection.
        // - when render is called after adding a new
        //   contact to the collection, a Backbone Model
        //   is passed to render. In that case use the default sort.
        console.debug('sort:', sort);
        if (sort instanceof Backbone.Model) {
            sort = this.sort;
        } else {
            this.sort = sort;
        }

        // sort the collection
        this.contacts.sortByField(sort);

        // reset the view
        this.$el.empty();

        // render the sorted contacts
        this.contacts.each(
            function( item ) { 
                this.addContactView( item ); 
            }, this 
        );
    }

});

// Contacts View item
var ContactView = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName: 'li',
    className: 'hideContact',
    template: _.template($('#contact_view').html() ),

    events: {
        'click #editContact' : 'toggleVisible',
        'click #delete' : 'deleteContact'
    },

    initialize: function() {
        console.debug('ContactView.initialize');
    },

    render: function() {
        console.debug('ContactView.render');

        // this.el is what we defined in tagName. 
        // use $el to get access to jQuery html() function
        this.$el.html( this.template( this.model.toJSON() ));

        return this;
    },

    deleteContact: function() {
        console.debug('ContactView.deleteContact');

        // Delete model
        this.model.destroy();

        // Delete view
        this.remove();
    },

    toggleVisible: function( e ) {
        console.debug('ContactView.toggleVisible');
        e.preventDefault();
        this.$el.toggleClass( 'hideContact' );
    }
});

// CreateContacts View
var CreateContactView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: $("#addContact"),
    contacts: '',

    events: {
        'click #add' : 'addContact'
    },

    initialize: function(contactsCollection) {
        console.debug('CreateContactView.initialize');

        // set contacts collection
        this.contacts = contactsCollection;
     },

    // Add a new contact to the contacts collection from form data.
    addContact: function( e ) {
        console.debug('CreateContactView.addContact');

        e.preventDefault();

        var formData = _.object(_.map($('#addContact').serializeArray(), _.values));

        // Collection will call the REST endpoint to store a new contact.
        this.contacts.create(formData);

        this.resetView();
    },

    resetView: function() {
        console.debug('CreateContactView.resetView');

        // reset the addContact form
        hideaddcontact('add-contact-list');
        showaddcontact('add-contact-mobile-container');
        document.getElementById("addContact").reset();
    }

});

// Contact Collection
var ContactList = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    
    // reference to this collections model.
    model: Contact,
    url: '/addressbook',
    sort_key: 'lastName',

    comparator: function (contact) {
        return contact.get(this.sort_key);
    },

    sortByField: function(fieldName) {
        this.sort_key = fieldName;
        this.sort();
    },

    initialize: function() {
        console.log('ContactList.initialize');
    }

});

// Contact Model
var Contact = Backbone.Model.extend({
   
    // default contact information
    // - el : id of the contact list item
    // - email : email
    // - firstName : first Name
    // - lastName : last Name
    // - cid : contact id
    // - eid : event id
    // - emailid : email id
    // - month : birthday month
    // - day : birthday day
    defaults: {
        el: '',
        email: '',
        firstName: '',
        lastName: '',
        cid: '',
        eid: '',
        emailid: '',
        month: '',
        day: ''
    },

    initialize: function( data ) {
        console.log('Contact.initialize');
        this.set('id', data.cid);
    }

});

Example of bootstrapped data:
var contacts = [

    {
        email : "jbanks@volcano.com", 
        firstName : "Joseph",
        lastName : "Banks",
        cid : "408416",
        el : "#408416",
        eid : "318665",
        emailid : "380177",
        month : "3",
        day : "17"
    }
    ,


    {
        email : "jbean@whisky.com", 
        firstName : "Jim",
        lastName : "Bean",
        cid : "408435",
        el : "#408435",
        eid : "318696",
        emailid : "380196",
        month : "5",
        day : "7"
    }
    ,


    {
        email : "ben@skywalkerranch.com", 
        firstName : "Uncle",
        lastName : "Ben",
        cid : "406536",
        el : "#406536",
        eid : "317817",
        emailid : "378239",
        month : "1",
        day : "14"
    }
    ,


    {
        email : "beru@skywalkerranch.com", 
        firstName : "Aunt",
        lastName : "Beru",
        cid : "406537",
        el : "#406537",
        eid : "",
        emailid : "378240",
        month : "None",
        day : "None"
    }];
```

**HTML:**

```html
<div class="container">

<form id="addContact" action="#" name="addContact" class="frmaddrbook">
<input type="hidden" value="" name="numrecs">
<input type="hidden" name="mode" value="">

<fieldset id="fs-addab">
        <ol class="sort-list">
            <li class="fname">First name</li>
            <li class="lname">Last name</li>
            <li class="email">E-mail address</li>
            <li class="bday">Birthday</li>
        </ol>

    <ol id="add-contact-list">
        <li>
            <span>
                <label for="fldFname">First name:</label>
                <input id="fldFname" name="firstName" class="text fname" type="text" maxlength="200" value="">
            </span>
            <span>
                <label for="fldLname">Last name:</label>
                <input id="fldLname" name="lastName" class="text lname" type="text" maxlength="200" value="">
            </span>
            <span>
                <label for="fldEmail">E-mail address:</label>
                <input id="fldEmail" name="email" class="text email" type="text" maxlength="256" value="">
            </span>
            <span>
                <label for="month">Month:</label>
                <select class="selMonth" name="month" id="month">
                    <option value="" selected="selected"></option>
                    <option value="01">January</option>
                    <option value="02">February</option>
                    <option value="03">March</option>
                    <option value="04">April</option>
                    <option value="05">May</option>
                    <option value="06">June</option>
                    <option value="07">July</option>
                    <option value="08">August</option>
                    <option value="09">September</option>
                    <option value="10">October</option>
                    <option value="11">November</option>
                    <option value="12">December</option>
                </select>
            </span>
            <span>
                <label for="day">Day:</label>
                <select class="selDay" name="day" id="day">
                    <option value="" selected="selected"></option>
                    <option value="01"> 1</option>
                    <option value="02"> 2</option>
                    <option value="03"> 3</option>
                    <option value="04"> 4</option>
                    <option value="05"> 5</option>
                    <option value="06"> 6</option>
                    <option value="07"> 7</option>
                    <option value="08"> 8</option>
                    <option value="09"> 9</option>
                    <option value="10">10</option>
                    <option value="11">11</option>
                    <option value="12">12</option>
                    <option value="13">13</option>
                    <option value="14">14</option>
                    <option value="15">15</option>
                    <option value="16">16</option>
                    <option value="17">17</option>
                    <option value="18">18</option>
                    <option value="19">19</option>
                    <option value="20">20</option>
                    <option value="21">21</option>
                    <option value="22">22</option>
                    <option value="23">23</option>
                    <option value="24">24</option>
                    <option value="25">25</option>
                    <option value="26">26</option>
                    <option value="27">27</option>
                    <option value="28">28</option>
                    <option value="29">29</option>
                    <option value="30">30</option>
                    <option value="31">31</option>
                </select>
            </span>
            <span>
                <input id="add" name="btnAddressBook" type="button" value="Add" class="mbutton">
            </span>
        </li>
    </ol>

</fieldset>
</form>


<p class="intro"><strong class="title">Update an Entry</strong>  Please click any of the column headings to sort the list in order of that column.</p>
<ol class="sort-list">
    <li class="fname"><a href="#firstName">First name</a></li>
    <li class="lname"><a href="#lastName">Last name</a></li>
    <li class="email"><a href="#email">E-mail address</a></li>
    <li class="bday">Birthday</li>
</ol>

 <form action="#" class="frmaddrbook" name="frmAddressbook0" id="frmABupdate0">
 <fieldset class="fs-editab">
    <ol id="address-list">
    <li class="hideContact" id="408416">
        <input type="hidden" value="380177" name="emailid">
        <input type="hidden" value="408416" name="cid">
        <input type="hidden" value="318665" name="eid">
        <span>
            <label for="fldFname0">First name</label>
            <input type="text" value="Joseph" maxlength="200" class="text fname" name="firstName" id="fldFname0">
        </span>
        <span>
            <label for="fldLname0">Last name</label>
            <input type="text" value="Banks" maxlength="200" class="text lname" name="lastName" id="fldLname0">
        </span>
        <span>
            <label for="fldEmail0">E-mail address</label>
            <input type="text" value="jbanks@volcano.com" maxlength="256" class="text email" name="email" id="fldEmail0">
            <button id="editContact"></button>
        </span>
        <span>
            <label for="month">Month:</label>
            <select name="month" class="selMonth">
                <option value=""></option>
                    <option value="1">January</option>
                    <option value="2">February</option>
                    <option value="3" selected="">March</option>
                    <option value="4">April</option>
                    <option value="5">May</option>
                    <option value="6">June</option>
                    <option value="7">July</option>
                    <option value="8">August</option>
                    <option value="9">September</option>
                    <option value="10">October</option>
                    <option value="11">November</option>
                    <option value="12">December</option>
            </select>
        </span>
        <span>
            <label for="day">Day:</label>
            <select name="day" class="selDay">
                <option value=""></option>
                    <option value="1">1</option>
                    <option value="2">2</option>
                    <option value="3">3</option>
                    <option value="4">4</option>
                    <option value="5">5</option>
                    <option value="6">6</option>
                    <option value="7">7</option>
                    <option value="8">8</option>
                    <option value="9">9</option>
                    <option value="10">10</option>
                    <option value="11">11</option>
                    <option value="12">12</option>
                    <option value="13">13</option>
                    <option value="14">14</option>
                    <option value="15">15</option>
                    <option value="16">16</option>
                    <option value="17" selected="">17</option>
                    <option value="18">18</option>
                    <option value="19">19</option>
                    <option value="20">20</option>
                    <option value="21">21</option>
                    <option value="22">22</option>
                    <option value="23">23</option>
                    <option value="24">24</option>
                    <option value="25">25</option>
                    <option value="26">26</option>
                    <option value="27">27</option>
                    <option value="28">28</option>
                    <option value="29">29</option>
                    <option value="30">30</option>
                    <option value="31">31</option>
            </select>
        </span>
        <span>
            <input type="button" value="Update" name="update" id="update" class="mbutton">
            <input type="button" value="Delete" name="delete" id="delete" class="mbutton button-alt">
        </span>
    </li>
    
    <li class="hideContact" id="408435">
        <input type="hidden" value="380196" name="emailid">
        <input type="hidden" value="408435" name="cid">
        <input type="hidden" value="318696" name="eid">
        <span>
            <label for="fldFname0">First name</label>
            <input type="text" value="Jim" maxlength="200" class="text fname" name="firstName" id="fldFname0">
        </span>
        <span>
            <label for="fldLname0">Last name</label>
            <input type="text" value="Bean" maxlength="200" class="text lname" name="lastName" id="fldLname0">
        </span>
        <span>
            <label for="fldEmail0">E-mail address</label>
            <input type="text" value="jbean@whisky.com" maxlength="256" class="text email" name="email" id="fldEmail0">
            <button id="editContact"></button>
        </span>
        <span>
            <label for="month">Month:</label>
            <select name="month" class="selMonth">
                <option value=""></option>
                    <option value="1">January</option>
                    <option value="2">February</option>
                    <option value="3">March</option>
                    <option value="4">April</option>
                    <option value="5" selected="">May</option>
                    <option value="6">June</option>
                    <option value="7">July</option>
                    <option value="8">August</option>
                    <option value="9">September</option>
                    <option value="10">October</option>
                    <option value="11">November</option>
                    <option value="12">December</option>
            </select>
        </span>
        <span>
            <label for="day">Day:</label>
            <select name="day" class="selDay">
                <option value=""></option>
                    <option value="1">1</option>
                    <option value="2">2</option>
                    <option value="3">3</option>
                    <option value="4">4</option>
                    <option value="5">5</option>
                    <option value="6">6</option>
                    <option value="7" selected="">7</option>
                    <option value="8">8</option>
                    <option value="9">9</option>
                    <option value="10">10</option>
                    <option value="11">11</option>
                    <option value="12">12</option>
                    <option value="13">13</option>
                    <option value="14">14</option>
                    <option value="15">15</option>
                    <option value="16">16</option>
                    <option value="17">17</option>
                    <option value="18">18</option>
                    <option value="19">19</option>
                    <option value="20">20</option>
                    <option value="21">21</option>
                    <option value="22">22</option>
                    <option value="23">23</option>
                    <option value="24">24</option>
                    <option value="25">25</option>
                    <option value="26">26</option>
                    <option value="27">27</option>
                    <option value="28">28</option>
                    <option value="29">29</option>
                    <option value="30">30</option>
                    <option value="31">31</option>
            </select>
        </span>
        <span>
            <input type="button" value="Update" name="update" id="update" class="mbutton">
            <input type="button" value="Delete" name="delete" id="delete" class="mbutton button-alt">
        </span>
    </li>
    </ol>
    </fieldset>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: it's better to provide HTML too

Answer (score 0):

Was able to solve this issue by passing in el and id from the model when instantiating my ContactView.

```js
// Instantiate a view for each contact in the collection.
createContactViewsForCollection: function(contacts) {
  console.debug('AppView.createViewsForCollection');
  this.contacts.each(
    function(contact) {
      var view = new ContactView({
        model: contact,
        el: contact.attributes.el,
        id: contact.attributes.cid
      });
      this.contactViews.push(view);
    }, this
  );
},
```